# How to find the probalities of a,b,c (mutually exclusive events) when i turn the problem into three binary classification problems?

Tags: machine-learning, probability, python, descriptive-statistics, scikit-learn

I am using scikits linear logisitc regression to classify three events a,b and c. it works better (score) when i convert them into a binary classification model. such as:
 1. M1 classifies a or b
 2. M2 classifies b or c
 3. M3 classifies a or c

when i predict the probabilities using the apropiate function i get from the models:

1. M1->P1(a), P1(b)
2. M2->P2(b), P2(c)
3. M3->P3(a), P3(c)

How do i compute the probability of each of the three events? do i average them? 
such as:

P(a) = (P1(a) + P3(a))/2 ?

is this the correct thing to do?

if not any suggestions?

thank you in advance.

Comment: why not use multinomial logistic regression?

Comment: Can i change the parametters in the logistic regression in scikit learn to do this? if you can provide a link i would be greatfull. But, about what i mentioned above? will averaging the probabilities work out?

Comment: I don't use `scikit` so I can't answer specifically, but if you know how to implement logistic regression, it's an extension. Averaging probability is clearly wrong, but I don't have the time to explain it in detail.

Comment: i understand now that in this case this constitues a one versus all senario.